# Generate two different list comprehensions using a single iterable

Tags: python, refactoring

For getting the major and minor diagonal of a matrix I could use:

```
major, minor = list(
    map(list, zip(*([(row[i], row[-i - 1]) for i, row in enumerate(mat)]))))
```

But, does there exist a better (pythonic) way of selecting the items in list comprehensions so that I don't have to transpose it later?

Also can it be extended to creating more lists(eg. 3 separate lists for `int`'s, `strings` and `floats` in a list)?

Comment: A list comprehension always produces a single list object, so no, you can't use just a list comprehension.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not even as a tuple?

Comment: That makes no sense. A list comprehension produces lists, not tuples.

Comment: Side note: The outer `list()` call is redundant; to assign to two targets Python already will iterate over the right-hand result.

Comment: But would it not return a `map` object, I used it to convert it to a `list`. Also am I not getting a list of tuples in the snippet I provided?

Comment: Yes, it returns a `map()`, but you can't assign a single map to two targets. Python then iterates over the `map()` to extract values to assign to the targets (`major = next(resulting_map)`, `minor = next(resulting_map)`, and if there are more elements left in `resulting_map`, raise an exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no need to go to such lengths to use one list comprehension. It is less readable, harder to maintain, and *no faster* than using two separate list comprehensions:

```
major = [row[i] for i, row in enumerate(mat)]
minor = [row[-i] for i, row in enumerate(mat, 1)]
```

Yes, the `zip(*...)` trick can be used to extract any number of elements from a list of tuples, just produce more elements in the tuple. However, the technique does should simply not be used.

Comment: I tried this before and I thought I there was some kind of duplication which could be avoided, see my code here: https://gist.github.com/ArchKudo/1db4271ae42924f028306d56a277a1a2 Anyways, thanks for the help!